# pass by ref C# button_on_click

Tags: c#, onclick, pass-by-reference

I'm creating a donation application that reads the input in a textbox, converts it to a double. Then using the method `operatingCost`, it should take that converted double and divide it by 17% (operating fees). Currently in the method, I have the variable `dontationBFees` coming in and then being divided by 17 and creating a new variable `afterFees`. The problem I'm having is that I need to pass by ref in this project and I cant seem to access the `afterFees` variable. I need to get the ref `afterFees` and have it displayed to my `afterFeesBox`. Also I have this method inside my button `on_click`. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
   private Double donationBFees = 0;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String donationBeforeFees;
        Double aFees;
        String totalDonationRaised;

        donationBeforeFees = donationBox.Text;
        donationBFees = System.Convert.ToDouble(donationBeforeFees);

        void operatingCost(ref double afterFees)
        {
            afterFees = (donationBFees / 17);
        }


        afterFeesBox.Text = operatingCost(ref afterFees);


    }
```

Comment: How/where do you declare `afterFees`?

Comment: Side note: for monetary values, use `decimal`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when

Comment: Refactor suggestion: put your `void operatingCost(ref double afterFees)` method outside of your click event method. Btw. it returns `void` - you cant assign it to a text property that way. I would do the following: change your method to `double operatingCost(double fees)` call it like `afterFees = operatingCost(donationBFees)` - no ref needed. Everything untested, please check if it is still your wanted output!

Comment: _"I need to pass by ref in this project"_ - why is that?

Comment: @Greg I declare afterFees in the method and its also created there.

Comment: @Fildor The project calls for the us of pass by ref to be used. If I didn't need it, this would be a lot easier but I cant seem to get the pass by ref working.

Comment: @nilsK Thanks for the void tip. I was doing that originally but the project calls for the use of pass by ref so its needed. When I had it outside of my btnClick, I tired calling it using operatingCost(ref afterFees) and it wasnt working.

Comment: What do you mean `divide by 17%`? Maybe it's `afterFees = afterFees - (afterFees * .17D);` in `operatingCost()` Then you can use a new variable:  `double donationAfterFees = donationBFees; operatingCost(ref donationAfterFees); afterFeesBox.Text = donationAfterFees.ToString();`. The use of `ref` in this inline function is weird. Also, as already stated, when you are calculating currency, use decimal, not double (ever).

Comment: That is really an odd convention for a c# project. But well, so be it. You need to declare a variable first,  then pass it by ref, then use it. Side note: you may want to add some validation. Never trust user input.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I was thinking of adding a if statement to check if the user input is validate i.e. no strings. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few (hopefully helpful) things:

```
void operatingCost(ref double afterFees)
{
    afterFees = (donationBFees / 17);
}
```

This means that you are passing in a reference to `afterFees` and, in the method, doing things to `afterFees` (this this case, assigning it to `donationBFees / 17`), and not returning anything.  However, this line:

```
afterFeesBox.Text = operatingCost(ref afterFees);
```

means you are assigning `Text` to the result of that method, which doesn't work since it's return type is `void`.

You also never declare `afterFees`, except in that method (which doesn't work).  I imagine you are getting an error "The name... does not exist in the current context."  You need to declare this variable locally (and rename it to not conflict):

```
double partAfterFees = 0;
operatingCost(ref partAfterFees);
```

So a few things you could do:

1) return a type (you are currently using `double` but, as suggested in the comments, may want to use `decimal`).  Then you could remove the `ref` if you want.  You could then do something like:

```
double operatingCost(ref double afterFees)
{
    afterFees = (donationBFees / 17);
    return afterFees;
}
afterFeesBox.Text = operatingCost(ref partAfterFees).ToString();
```

But this seems odd, so I may just do (given what you've said):

```
double partAfterFees = 0;
operatingCost(ref partAfterFees);
afterFeesBox.Text = partAfterFees.ToString();
```

Note, there are "better" solutions involving refactoring and checking for valid input, etc. But I think this answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I changed a few things in my code. I noticed (with help) that my calculations for percentage where off. I fixed that by trial and error and now its working. I also changed to decimal instead of double as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Calling byref changes the value that is passed into a function, so you need to pass in a variable that you don't mind being change.

In this example I've had two things called afterFees, so I renamed one to make it obvious that one is a parameter.

```
private Double donationBFees = 0;

void operatingCost(ref double afterFeesParam)
{
    afterFeesParam = (afterFeesParam / 17);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String donationBeforeFees;
    Double aFees;
    String totalDonationRaised;

    donationBeforeFees = donationBox.Text;
    donationBFees = System.Convert.ToDouble(donationBeforeFees);

    double afterFees = donationBFees;
    operatingCost(ref afterFees);
    afterFeesBox.Text = afterFees;
}
```

You should tell your prof that this is not really a good use of a byref parameter. It might make more sense if the function deducted the operating cost:

```
void deductOperatingCost(ref double afterFeesParam)
{
    afterFeesParam = afterFeesParam - (afterFeesParam / 17);
}
```

That way you give it a value and it comes back slightly smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much Robin. This helped me out greatly. I kept the afterFeesParam in my code to not get confused with the other variables. I also changed to decimal as suggested by other and I also noticed I was calculating the percentage wrong so I fixed that. Thank you for all of the advise and help.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the method out of the onClick, I changed the calculation for finding the percentage of the donation (user input). I also formatted the output to display only two places after the decimal and display a dollar sign. I still need to create error handlers to validate the user input but that shouldn't be an issue. I had issues with the pass by ref but I have a lot better understand how it works. Thank you everyone for the help!

```
private decimal donationBFees = 0;

    void deductOperatingCost(ref decimal afterFeesParam)
    {
        afterFeesParam = afterFeesParam - (afterFeesParam  / 100 * 17);
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String donationBeforeFees;
        Decimal aFees;
        String totalDonationRaised;

        donationBeforeFees = donationBox.Text;
        donationBFees = System.Convert.ToDecimal(donationBeforeFees);


        decimal afterFees = donationBFees;
        deductOperatingCost(ref afterFees);
        afterFeesBox.Text = afterFees.ToString("$###, ##0.00");

    }
```

Comment: Introducing donationBFees as class field is not the best idea, because it can lead to unwanted side-effects. A local declaration would absolutely be enough.